# Resultado de array retorna null

Tags: php, html, mysqli

- Eu preciso que a partir na opção selecionada no `<select>`, eu
  consulte no banco o que há relacionado a esta opção. Fiz isso da
  maneira que segue abaixo, mas na parte `$p_id  = $result['p_id'];`,
  há retorno nulo, já utilizei esse código de associação de array
  outras vezes e funcionou.
- Necessito também, que isso tudo fique oculto até o momento da escolha
  do `<option>`, após exiba o que eu fiz, com os registros. Não sei o
  que está errado, mas aceito sugestões de solução e agradeço desde já.

  ```
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Cliente</label>
                        <select class="form-control m-b-10" required="required" name="e_id" charset="utf-8">
                          <option>Selecione o cliente</option>
                            <?php
                              $select  = "SELECT e_id, nome FROM pessoas"; 
                              $result  = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);
                              while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                $e_id = $exibe['e_id'];
                                echo '<option  charset="utf-8" value = '. $e_id . '>' . $exibe['nome'] . '</option>';
                              }                                    
                              mysqli_free_result($result); 
                            ?>                     
                        </select> 

                      </div>                                  
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <!--<button name="salvar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="showElement();">Pesquisar</button>-->
                    <div id="dados" class="form-group" onload="hideElement();">                                                       
                          <?php
                          if ($e_id <> '') {
                            $select  = "SELECT p_id FROM itens WHERE e_id = '$e_id'";  
                            $result  = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conexao, $select));
                            $p_id  = $result['p_id'];
                            $select2 = "SELECT descricao where p_id = '$p_id'";
                            $resulta = mysqli_query($conexao, $select2);          
                            if (mysqli_num_rows($resulta) > 0){                            
                            echo '<table class="table table-hover" >
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Descrição</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>';
                              while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)){ 
                                  $p_id  = $exibe['p_id'];
                                  echo '<tr>';  
                                    echo '<td value = "">' . $exibe['descricao']      . '</td>';                   
                            }
                          }else{
                            echo '<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Não há registros</label>'; 
                          } 
                        }else{
                          echo '<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Não há registros</label>';
                        }             
                        mysqli_free_result($result);  
                        mysqli_free_result($resulta);                                                                              
                          ?>                                     
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
  ```

Comment: Seu código parece não fazer muito sentido (desculpe-me se caso eu não tenha entendido corretamente), mas você sabe diferenciar linguagem *client-side* de linguagem *server-side*? O PHP é *server-side*, mas parece que você tentou utilizá-la como se fosse *client-side*, tal como JavaScript.

Comment: Você tentou com: do{ //código.... } while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta));

Comment: explica seu código lá de cima. Está tudo em uma página só?

Comment: Concordo com o @AndersonCarlosWoss. Eu até faria de outra forma: Colocar um `form` com `action` pra mesma página e um gatilho com *jQuery* ou *Javascript* para dar um `submit` no evento `change` do `select`. Caso não possa ter um "refresh" na sua aplicação, pode fazer (também) com *ajax*.

Answer (score 0):

> Eu preciso que a partir na opção selecionada no select, eu consulte no banco o que há relacionado a esta opção.

Não tem como utilizar o **PHP** no *client-side* (@AndersonCarlosWoss).

Para isso, **pode-se**:

- Fazer uma segunda página que *mostra* a descrição de acordo com o *id* passado pelo método *get* do formulário;
- Submeter o formulário no evento `change` do `<select>` com uma requisição *AJAX*;
- Mostrar os dados da requisição (conteúdo da segunda página) em uma `div`;

Entendendo isso, vamos ao código:

***index.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#slcClientes').on('change', function() {
                    var dados = jQuery( '#fmrClientes' ).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: $('#fmrClientes').attr('action'),
                        data: dados,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#dvAlvo').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="fmrClientes" action="get_obs.php" method="post">
            <select id="slcClientes" name="cl_id">
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Selecione:</option>
            <?php

                $conexao = mysqli_connect("host", "usuário", "senha", "banco de dados"); // CONFIGURE!!!
                $res = mysqli_query( $conexao, "SELECT `ClID`, `ClNome` FROM `clientes` LIMIT 0,10;"); // LIMITEI PARA 10 REGISTROS - SOMENTE PARA FINS DE TESTE
                if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
                {
                    while( $cl = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) )
                    {
                        echo "<option value=" . $cl['ClID'] . ">" . $cl['ClNome'] . "</option>";
                    }
                }

            ?>
            </select>
        </form>

        <div id="dvAlvo">
            <!-- ALVO DA REQUISIÇÃO AJAX -->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

***get_obs.php***

```
<?php

    $conexao = mysqli_connect("host", "usuário", "senha", "banco de dados"); // CONFIGURE!!!
    $id = $_POST['cl_id'];
    $res = mysqli_query( $conexao, "SELECT `ClOBS` FROM `clientes` WHERE `ClID` = '" . $id . "';");
    $desc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo nl2br( htmlspecialchars( $desc['ClOBS'] ) );

?>
```

**Estrutura da tabela *clientes***:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ClID    | int(5)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ClNome  | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ClObs   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Lembre-se de configurar a variável `$conexao` nos dois arquivos!

> Necessito também, que isso tudo fique oculto até o momento da escolha do option, após exiba o que eu fiz, com os registros.

Como a `div` alvo está vazia, o conteúdo somente será mostrado nela ao selecionar alguma opção do `select`. O gatilho está na *linha 7* do `index.php`.

O código que elaborei está 100% funcional. Testado já com **PHP 7**. Porém, trato a *descrição* como *observação* em meu código.

Não me importei com validação do formulário. Faça isso você mesmo. Esse código é com fins de orientação.

Dica caso hajam muitos clientes: Ao invés de fazer um `select` mostrando **todos** os clientes cadastrados, recomendo você criar um `input[type=text]` com `autocomplete` do *jQuery*.

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar!

Comment: Teste aí e dê um feedback! Estou aguardando! Se necessário, sugira algo pra melhorar o código.

Comment: Não deu certo, não ocorre nada!

Comment: Como não ocorre nada?! Poste o erro. Mesmo que seja no console, deve gerar algum erro! Esse código foi testado e funcionou 100% comigo. Talvez seja o nome das tabelas que está diferente. Deve mudar aí.

Comment: O value com id deste trecho: `echo "<option value=" . $cl['ClID'] . ">" . $cl['ClNome'] . "</option>";` fica ok no html, está preenchendo correto, mas no arquivo php ocorre o seguinte erro: `Undefined index: $id`, devido a isso quando verifico com `var_dump` o resultado, retorna null. Não entendo porque o php não recebe o id.

Comment: @R.Gasparin : Mas vc deve estar usando a variável `$id` como índice de algum vetor (*array*). O correto é o `$id` receber o valor de `$_POST['cl_id']`, onde `cl_id` é o `name` do `input` no seu formulário. Se você simplesmente copiar e colar o código que fiz, vai funcionar 100%. Testei aqui e está tudo ok.

Comment: No meu código eu preciso captar o id do primeiro option e usá-lo no próximo select para obter outro id de outra tabela, pois o que preciso exibir vem desse segundo select. No meu código, fiz de maneira que normalmente consigo captar um id de outra tabela, mas não seu por qual motivo esse id não é captado. Isso tudo que eu falei é no código colocado na pergunta.